# How to list AWS tagged Hosted Zones using ResourceGroupsTaggingAPI boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

I am trying to retrieve all the AWS resources tagged using the boto3 ResourceGroupsTaggingAPI, but I can't seem to retrieve the Hosted Zones which have been tagged.

```
tagFilters = [{'Key': 'tagA', 'Values': 'a'}, {'Key': 'tagB', 'Values': 'b'}]
client = boto3.client('resourcegroupstaggingapi', region_name = 'us-east-2')

paginator = self.client.get_paginator('get_resources')
page_list = paginator.paginate(TagFilters = tagFilters)

# filter and get iterable object arn
# Refer filtering with JMESPath => http://jmespath.org/
arns = page_list.search("ResourceTagMappingList[*].ResourceARN")

for arn in arns:
    print(arn)
```

I noticed through the Tag Editor in the **AWS Console** (which I guess is using the ResourceGroupsTaggingAPI) when the region is set to All the tagged Hosted zones can be retrieved (since global) while when a specific region is set the tagged Hosted Zones are not shown in the results. Is there a way to set the boto3 client region to all?, or is there another way to do this?

I have already tried

```
client = boto3.client('resourcegroupstaggingapi')
```

which returns an empty result
(https://console.aws.amazon.com/resource-groups/tag-editor/find-resources?region=us-east-1)

Comment: When creating the client object, can you try using us-east-1 as the region instead of us-east-2 and see if that yields the results?

Comment: @krishna_mee2004 seems setting us-east-1 works, do hosted zones reside here?

Comment: If you want to speed things up, please also consider using a ResourceTypeFilter: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/resourcegroupstagging/latest/APIReference/API_GetResources.html#resourcegrouptagging-GetResources-request-ResourceTypeFilters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate it over all regions,

```
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
region_response = ec2.describe_regions()
#print('Regions:', region_response['Regions'])
for this_region_info in region_response['Regions']:
  region = this_region_info["RegionName"]
  my_config = Config(
    region_name = region
  )
  client = boto3.client('resourcegroupstaggingapi', config=my_config)
```

Answer (score 0):

Soumyadip De's solution does not work anymore. Use the client without adding any Config when creating the client. It is important to note that not all services or regions can be used with it.
"You can only tag resources that are located in the specified Amazon Web Services Region for the Amazon Web Services account." - [boto3 docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/resourcegroupstaggingapi/client/tag_resources.html)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).